# How to share a package without CTAN

Tags: packages

(Honestly I fear this is borderline off-topic... be gentle with the downvotes `;-)`)

Most of the packages I've written are for personal use but a couple of them are used by some other people. These packages change relatively often as I'm constantly implementing requested features. Right now I tend to ship out the most recent stable version by e-mail but then I get either answers of people that are not interested any more, or requests from other people who aren't in the mailing list yet.

I do *not* want to upload the packages on CTAN for two reasons:

1. There's maybe a dozen users. It's highly unlikely the packages will be useful to someone else.
2. I find there is enough bad code on CTAN without me contributing to it.

For now I've got an institutional home page but that may change any minute, so posting the code there for download (which I've done) might not be a long-term solution.

Any advice? (My personal texmf tree is on Dropbox, if that may spurt a solution.)

Comment: GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket, etc. Any of those. If you push a new tag (release), people interested can get notified (and can unsubscribe from that themselves). It also features an easy way to get the latest release as ZIP (actions), or direct code (clone), if you also provide an `l3build`-file all they have to do after cloning is running `l3build install` in the project's main folder.

Comment: @Skillmon OK, I'll have to google every single word of your comment 

Comment: Agree with @Skillmon although this is technically off topic for meta; and marginally on topic (though fundamentally opinion based) on the main site. I release some packages of mine on CTAN, but others, even ones that I know are in use, are only released via GitHub, mainly because I'm not convinced enough of their robustness, or I haven't managed to document them to my satisfaction. I'm not sure your point 1 is a valid reason though. One thing I do know is that packages not released via CTAN are more of a pain to help others who use them.

Comment: github is the default option these days (others are available) but latex, tikz, ... are available on github before being moved to ctan

Comment: Regarding upload to CTAN: I would try to upload it as long as the code serves its purposes well enough. Even if it may not be perfect.That would not preclude publication on Git-whatever. The Git issue page is in many cases directly linked from the CTAN page. Moreover, since it can reach a bigger group of users if its on CTAN, it also increases the chances that some of them may find some drawbacks and can report them via Gitxxx. Which in the end, makes the code even better. All of this, of course, only if you're willing to write a doc (which can be a big obstacle, as I know myself) ;-)

Comment: You do not have your own web page?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have your code in a version control system such as `git` the natural distribution channel besides CTAN would be any of the major hosters which support the version control system of your choice (and if you don't yet have your code in a version control system, I strongly recommend that you start doing so).

For `git` (which ought to be the most used version control software nowadays) the major players would be sites such as GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket, or smaller (or even self-hosted) alternatives. If you push a new release to your repository (in `git` this would be a `tag`), you can set things up by continuous integration such that a ZIP-archive (or similar) is built automatically (you could also run a test-suite against your new code to check that your changes don't break anything). Also anyone following your repository (nomenclature for "following" might vary between the different providers) would get an email notification about your new release (for instance, I get a notification for any LaTeX3 release because I'm watching the l3kernel repository on GitHub).

Getting your package code would then simply be a matter of either downloading the provided archive from your releases-page (should be autogenerated), or by cloning your repository. In the latter case, if you include an `l3build` configuration file your users would simply run `l3build install` after cloning and have your package ready to go (`l3build` is included in TeX Live and MikTeX).

Anyone no longer interested in your code (because they don't need it anymore or for whatever reason) can simply unsubscribe from notifications of your repository.

Comment: This is good advice for git users, but isn't presenting it as an option for all users of version control a bit misleading? I would be very happy to be wrong about this but, as far as I know, the existence of suitable repositories is limited to git (unless you or your institution can host them privately). (And last time I looked, subversion still had better LaTeX support than git.)

Comment: @cfr how do you define "subversion still had better LaTeX support than git"? Because last time I checked git outperforms subversion on text files, and LaTeX is text files. But the ugly truth is: I'm not that well versed with public repositories that aren't git, but the principles should be the same in subversion as well (though of course my site list is limited to git-supporting ones) -- CI should be possible with svn, releases should be possible with svn, and if you find a hoster for your svn repo that one should have email subscriptions as well. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: What I had in mind was packages to support using version control information in documents. There's good support for subversion in documents, classes, packages, files etc., but I'm not aware of equivalent support for git. (Except I believe there is support for it in class/package declarations?) You're right about the parity in terms of releases etc. The problem is in the 'if' of 'if you find a hoster'. When I really need to post code like that, I put it in a git repo, but everything is still in subversion on my own machine, so I'm not using git for version control. It's just a hosting platform.

Comment: @cfr "What I had in mind was packages to support using version control information in documents." Can you give concrete examples?

Comment: @cfr ahh, so you mean LaTeX has better subversion support :) Yes, that's possibly true (but something I personally don't need, if I'd want to include the current commit in the document I'd change my build pipeline to produce a file with that information on the fly -- but I think there are LaTeX packages for `git` support, they might be inferior to the svn ones, though, I never tested/used them).

Comment: @cfr `gitinfo2` (but the fundamental difference in handling of revision data between Subversion and DCVS systems means it will never be quite the same)

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks. Yes, that's the other thing. I think `git` exceeds my cognitive capacities.

Comment: @cfr It comes down to Git/Mercurial/... don't place version data in the sources, whereas Subversion, CVS, etc. do

Comment: @JosephWright Ah, that's much simpler than other explanations I've (tried to) read. Thank-you. I think I'd miss that - it's so simple having the information right in the source and typeset output (for drafts, especially).

Comment: Thx. What's "_version control_"? `;-)` (Joke.) (Well, half-joke...)

Comment: @campa What should be "controlled"? Meta-joke. :-)

Answer (score 4):

[Skillmon's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/696991/48973) is certainly the best choice if you manage your code with Git. One big advantage for you being that sites like GitHub offer all the hosting and notification infrastructure for free.

If you do not want to use Git (though I think you should) and want to stick with email, a [Mailman](https://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/) server (or similar distribution service) would be an easy option. This would allow users to (un)subscribe autonomously and give you a single address to send your releases to. Of course, you need to have access to a server running the service.